# Default copy assignment operator with reference member?

Tags: c++

I am working on a hybrid legacy application (C++/C#) in Visual Studio 2017, for which I am currently trying to add logging to an existing class to help with diagnosing another issue.  The class in question is fairly straight-forward:

```
class CAnExampleClass : CAnExampleBaseClass
{
public:
    CAnExampleClass();
    virtual ~CAnExampleClass(void);

    // dozens of public methods
private:
    // a few private methods
public:
    // dozens of public member variables, all intrinsic types or custom types with copy constructors or arrays thereof
private:
    class AnExampleChildImpl;
    mutable std::shared_ptr<AnExampleChildImpl> _pImpl;
    // a couple of friend classes
    bool _anExampleFlag;
public:
    static const int NumberOfItems = 15;
}
```

In the implementation the constructor initialises the private member in the initialisation list like so:

```
CAnExampleClass::CAnExampleClass()
    : _anExampleFlag(false)
```

Following the pattern established elsewhere in the application, I have added a member to the class for the logger:

```
private:
    ILog& _log;
```

And initialised this member in the constructor's initialisation list:

```
CAnExampleClass::CAnExampleClass()
    : _anExampleFlag(false), _log(CMyLog::GetLogger("log_name"))
```

The logger is fairly simple:

```
class ILog
{
    ...
}
...
class CMyLog
{
public:
    ...
    static ILog& GetLogger(const char *loggerName);
    ...
}
```

However, now the compiler is reporting an error:

```
Error   C2280   'CAnExampleClass &CAnExampleClass::operator =(const CAnExampleClass &)': attempting to reference a deleted function ...
```

As it turns out, there are quite a few points throughout the application where the code relies on the default copy assignment operator to copy an existing instance of this class to a new instance.  It also just so happens that the other cases in which the logger has already been used is where there are no attempts to copy the class using the copy assignment operator.

My question is, therefore, is there any alternative to defining a custom copy assignment operator for `CAnExampleClass` and copying each (public) member and array over to the new instance?  It seems like overkill to me that this should be necessary when the reference member introduced is initialised in the constructor's initialisation list: that being the case, what is preventing the default copy assignment operator from functioning as before?  Why do I need to define a custom implementation of the operator when it will be doing, essentially, the exact same thing as the default implementation since the initialisation list is taking care of the reference member?  Is there a way to either have the default copy assignment operator ignore the reference member, or somehow call upon the default copy logic from a custom operator implementation?

Modifying code outside this class to deal with this issue is not a realistic option (application is too big, old, unwieldy, etc.)  Ideally, I'd like to avoid the custom assignment operator implementation option if there is a simpler way, as it (obviously) avoids having to manually re-create all those member assignments, but also to avoid the possibility that if another developer on the team later adds a member to this class they may inadvertently forget to update the copy assignment operator and we end up with some weird logic error in the code that relies on that operator.

Comment: There are times a non-owning pointer is just so much easier to deal with that you go with the pointer. If you gotta copy, use the pointer. The reference can't be reseated, so no matter what you do assignment is going to get weird.

Answer (score 0):

> what is preventing the default copy assignment operator from functioning as before?

You introduced a member to `CAnExampleClass` of type `ILog&`. References are non-reseatable. Once initialised, it can never change. Even if, because of your singleton pattern, the instances of `ILog` will always be the same, having a reference member will automatically delete the default assignment member functions.

Either you implement the assignment operator for all classes that have a reference member, which doesn't seem to be feasible for you or you drop the raw reference in favour of either a [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper):

```
std::reference_wrapper<ILog> _log; // <- reseatable reference
```

or you just drop the member entirely and always call `CMyLog::GetLogger("log_name")` when you need the log object, maybe encapsulating it in a static private member function:

```
static ILog& logger() {
  // this ONLY works if GetLogger always returns the same object
  return CMyLog::GetLogger("log_name");
}
```